# Does the measurability of $x\mapsto\operatorname P_x[A]$ imply the measurability of $x\mapsto\operatorname E_x[X]$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ and $(E,\mathcal E)$ be measurable spaces
- $(\operatorname P_x)_{x\in E}$ be a family of probability measures on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ such that $$E\ni x\mapsto\operatorname P_x[A]$$ is $\mathcal E$-measurable, for all $A\in\mathcal A$

Let $X$ be a $\mathcal A$-measurable random variable. Can we show, that $$E\ni x\mapsto\operatorname E_x[X]$$ is $\mathcal E$-measurable, too?

Comment: I don't see a problem. Each rv is a limit of simple rv's, whence the measurability.

Comment: @zhoraster: Yes, the so-called "standard mantra" of measure theory: indicator functions, simple functions, nonnegative functions, measurable functions.

Comment: @zhoraster Let $x^+:=\max(x,0)$. You're right. Each **nonnegative** measurable function is the monotone limit of "simple" functions. Thus, $$\operatorname E_x[X_n^+]=\lim_{n\to\infty}\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{m_n}\alpha_i^{(n)} \operatorname P_x\left[A_i^{(n)}\right]}_{=:\beta_x^{(n)}}$$ for some $m_n\in\mathbb N$, $\alpha_i^{(n)}\in[0,\infty)$ and $A_i^{(n)}\in\mathcal A$. By assumption $$E\ni x\mapsto\beta_x^{(n)}$$ is $\mathcal E$-measurable, for all $n\in\mathbb N$. So, the limit is $\mathcal E$-measurable, too. Right?

Comment: @zhoraster So, all we need for the claim to hold is boundedness of $X$, right? (Otherwise we cannot make use of the argumentation above in $\operatorname E_x[X]=\operatorname E_x[X^+]-\operatorname E_x[X^-]$)

Comment: @NateEldredge You might want to take notice of my comment, too.

Comment: Your argument is right. You don't need $X$ to be bounded, only integrable with respect to $E_x$ for every $x$.  In fact all you need is that $\{x : E_x[X^+] = +\infty\}$ and $\{x : E_x [X^-] = +\infty\}$ are disjoint.  (And if they're not then there are $x$ for which $E_x[X]$ is undefined, making your claim meaningless.)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the "approximation by simple functions" approach, one can use the monotone class theorem for functions, as found for example   [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem). The conditions of the theorem quoted there are met by taking the $\pi$-system to be your ${\mathcal A}$ and the vector space ${\mathcal H}$ to be the class of bounded ${\mathcal A}$-measurable functions $X:\Omega\to{\Bbb R}$ with the property that $x\mapsto{\Bbb E}_x[X]$ is ${\mathcal E}$ measurable.

This shows that the asserted measurability holds for all bounded ${\mathcal A}$-measurable $X$. The boundedness assumption can be relaxed by truncation arguments.